# Creating a series of buffers along a stream polygon at set intervals in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, arcgis-pro, buffer, land-use

I have a set of streamlines and a polygon layer showing the extents of water outwards from those lines. I will be buffering out 50-ft from the polygon layer to gather information about land-use in the area immediately adjacent to the stream. I am wondering how I might be able to break these buffers into intervals (10-ft or so) such that I have a set of rectangles (100 ft on each side of the stream but not including the stream itself) all touching each other. To make things a tad more complicated, it would be great to have the polygon on each side of the stream connected despite the gap where the stream is (ie. in attached image, polygon 1 would have two components: one on each side of stream).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Forget about rectangles, they are only possible if river is straight line.

Just split your lines at equal interval (Generate Points Along line and Split by points) and run Euclidean allocation:

[image]

Covert raster to polygon and erase parts under river polygons. Expect troubles at stream junctions and very bendy reaches.

Also 10/100 is not going to work, you need reverse ratio between them.